# If $Q$ is a nonnegative trace-class operator and $Ψ$ is Hilbert-Schmidt, are we able to show that $\mathcal R(ΨQ^{1/2})⊆\mathcal R(ΨQΨ^*)^{1/2}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, trace

Let

- $U,H,\mathcal H$ be separable $\mathbb R$-Hilbert spaces
- $Q\in\mathfrak L_1(U)$$^1$ be nonnegative and self-adjoint
- $\Psi\in\operatorname{HS}(Q^{1/2}U,H)$$^2$$^3$
- $\tilde Q:=\Psi Q\Psi^\ast$

> I want to show that $$\Psi Q^{1/2}U\subseteq\tilde Q^{1/2}H\;.\tag 1$$

Maybe there is a useful identity for the square-root $\tilde Q^{1/2}$ of $\tilde Q$. I wasn't able to find one. So, how can we show $(1)$?

---

$^1$ $\mathfrak L_1(A,B)$ denotes the space of nuclear operators from $A$ to $B$.

$^2$ $\operatorname{HS}(A,B)$ denotes the space of Hilbert-Schmidt operators from $A$ to $B$.

$^3$ If $R\in\mathfrak L_1(A)$ is nonnegative and self-adjoint, then $R^{1/2}A$ is considered as being equipped with $$\langle x,y\rangle_{R^{1/2}A}:=\langle R^{-1/2}x,R^{-1/2}y\rangle_A\;\;\;\text{for }x,y\in R^{1/2}A\;,$$ where $R^{-1}$ denotes the pseudo inverse of $R$.

Comment: Is  $\Psi Q \Psi^* $ compact and self-adjoint ? In that case SVD and spectral theorem

Comment: @reuins $\tilde Q$ is even nuclear. And since $Q$ is self-adjoint, it is self-adjoint as well. Maybe you can explain in more detail, how this helps to solve the problem.